# lwjgl model is not rotating at its center

Tags: opengl, 3d, lwjgl

I have an entity(triangle),when am trying to rotate its rotating in circular motion.When i applied the projection and transformation matrix its not centered either,it is to the right by some distance from center, i dont even know why its not centered[image]

transformation matrix along with vertices

```
float[] vertices = {
                1409.598f, -58.85f, 1471.946f,
                1460.572f, -58.9047f, 1462.047f,
                1408.506f, -20.5531f, 1471.137f
        };

public static Matrix4f createTransformationMatrix(Vector3f entity, float rx, float ry,
            float rz, float scale) {
        Matrix4f matrix = new Matrix4f();
        matrix.setIdentity();
        Matrix4f.translate(entity, matrix, matrix);
        Matrix4f.rotate((float) Math.toRadians(rx), new Vector3f(1,0,0), matrix, matrix);
        Matrix4f.rotate((float) Math.toRadians(ry), new Vector3f(0,1,0), matrix, matrix);
        Matrix4f.rotate((float) Math.toRadians(rz), new Vector3f(0,0,1), matrix, matrix);
        Matrix4f.scale(new Vector3f(scale,scale,scale), matrix, matrix);

        return matrix;
    }
```

Any help ?

Projection matrix:

```
private static final float FOV = 70;
private static final float NEAR_PLANE = 0.1f;
private static final float FAR_PLANE = 10000;

private void createProjectionMatrix() {
        float aspectRatio = (float) Display.getWidth() / (float) Display.getHeight();
        float y_scale = (float) ((1f / Math.tan(Math.toRadians(FOV / 2f))) * aspectRatio);
        float x_scale = y_scale / aspectRatio;
        float frustum_length = FAR_PLANE - NEAR_PLANE;

        projectionMatrix = new Matrix4f();
        projectionMatrix.m00 = x_scale;
        projectionMatrix.m11 = y_scale;
        projectionMatrix.m20 = 0f;
        projectionMatrix.m21 = 0f;
        projectionMatrix.m22 = -((FAR_PLANE + NEAR_PLANE) / frustum_length);
        projectionMatrix.m23 = -1;
        projectionMatrix.m32 = -((2 * NEAR_PLANE * FAR_PLANE) / frustum_length);
        projectionMatrix.m33 = 0;

    }
```

View Matrix:

```
public static Matrix4f createViewMatrix(Camera camera) {
        Matrix4f viewMatrix = new Matrix4f();
        viewMatrix.setIdentity();
        Matrix4f.rotate((float) Math.toRadians(camera.getPitch()), new Vector3f(1, 0, 0), viewMatrix,
                viewMatrix);
        Matrix4f.rotate((float) Math.toRadians(camera.getYaw()), new Vector3f(0, 1, 0), viewMatrix, viewMatrix);
        Vector3f cameraPos = camera.getPosition();

        Vector3f negativeCameraPos = new Vector3f(-cameraPos.x, -cameraPos.y, -cameraPos.z);
        Matrix4f.translate(negativeCameraPos, viewMatrix, viewMatrix);
        return viewMatrix;
    }
```

Vertex Shader:

```
#version 400 core

in vec3 position;

uniform mat4 transformationMatrix;
uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
uniform mat4 viewMatrix;

void main(void){

    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * viewMatrix * transformationMatrix * vec4(position,1.0);

}
```

Comment: A vertex coordinate suffers these transformations: Model->World->Camera->Projection->NDC->Window, each expressed by a 4x4 matrix (can be *Identity* if no transformation is applied) I can not find in your code how you do these transformations, at least the first four of them.

Comment: I have added projection and transformation matrix(Model matrix if am not wrong).please see edit

Comment: @ch.Joshielijah Your vertex coordinates are displaced, the center of the model is not around 0.

Comment: @Rabbid76 thanks am thinking the same how can i correct them ? am confused in doing that

Comment: @Rabbid76 I don't understand where to start and how to follow, any example on how to center them ? am working on them from more than a week now

Comment: @Rabbid76 the vertices are from the file.'setup some how' by that you mean trail and error ?

Comment: @httpdigest I tried the second one(translate them to center before rotation and then back) using transformationmatrix, what should be the axis vector positions in x,y and z and even scale. If you can give me the near transformation that works i am happy to mark it as answer.

Comment: If there is any thing that help me in writing translation-rotation-translation to points that are away from origin please provide me.I have already spend many days solving this,am even happy to learn more in future,I want to get this thing done.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have an error in projection matrix. Use this line:

```
 float y_scale = 1f / Math.tan(Math.toRadians(FOV / 2f));
```

Comment: Nothing has changed much ripi, the triangle became small.rotation not fixed.